# Professional Websites Built with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was asked at a .NET user group if I knew of any professional web sites built with the Razor view engine for MVC that they could peruse.  Interesting question, and I was not aware of any at the time.  Does anybody know of a publicized list or specific web sites that have implemented Razor?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a list but SO is one! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: @Ranhiru Yeah, that's what a developer was saying at the user group...  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was involved in building this one: http://snapshot.factiva.com. Bad news is that you need an account to be able to see it.

Here's a list of public websites which includes our own SO: http://www.findmyhosts.com/top-10-asp-net-mvc-framework-websites/